# The following extensions are missing! Please enable the PHP extension(s) in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I am trying to install phpMyFAQ and i am getting the error

`The following extensions are missing! Please enable the PHP extension(s) in php.ini.`

Can anybody help me where I can find the place where I can enable it?

Comment: Without more details about your system, the answer is no, nobody can help you. Please also search on this site and the rest of the internet for relevant instructions, because this is an **extremely** common task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using xampp, click on the apache config button > PHP(php.ini) and find the extension name then remove the semicolon (;) before it and save. If you're using cPanel, search "php version" you will find the extension there.
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlACj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Find your php.ini. Find the section which looks like:

```
extension=bz2
extension=curl
;extension=ffi
;extension=ftp
extension=fileinfo
extension=gd2
extension=gettext
;extension=gmp
extension=intl
extension=imap
;extension=ldap
extension=mbstring
extension=exif
extension=mysqli
;extension=oci8_12c
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

etc.

Delete the semicolon before the extension(s) you need. Restart your Apache. Done.

And by the way: Hours of trying yourself saves ten minutes reading the manual. Which means: RTFM!